# How do I add the generator point to an EC public key using OpenSSL?

Tags: c, cryptography, openssl

I have this but it does not work:

```
EC_GROUP * group = EC_GROUP_new_by_curve_name(NID_secp256k1);
EC_POINT * pub = EC_POINT_new(group);
EC_POINT * new = EC_POINT_new(group);
BN_CTX * ctx = BN_CTX_new();
EC_POINT_oct2point(group, pub, key->pubkey.key, 33, ctx);
EC_POINT_add(group, (EC_POINT *)EC_GROUP_get0_generator(group), pub, new, ctx);
EC_POINT_point2oct(group, new, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED, key->pubkey.key, 33, ctx);
BN_CTX_free(ctx);
EC_POINT_free(pub);
EC_POINT_free(new);
EC_GROUP_free(group);
```

The public key remains the same, except for the first byte which is not 2 or 3 for compressed keys but 0 (which I don't know what that is, or if it's even a valid type of public key).

Answer (score 1):

`EC_POINT_add(group, (EC_POINT *)EC_GROUP_get0_generator(group), pub, new, ctx);`

should be

`EC_POINT_add(group, new, (EC_POINT *)EC_GROUP_get0_generator(group), pub, ctx);`